# Best way to sync files from Dropbox "Apps" folder to regular Dropbox folders

Tags: microsoft-excel, sync, dropbox, cloud

A Dropbox account with voluminous files also syncs/receives files through a third-party app integration, which files arrive within that app-integration's designated folder within Dropbox's "Apps" folder. To my knowledge, Dropbox does not permit third-party Apps integrations to sync files directly into Dropbox's main file system. (If I'm wrong about that, please show me how!)

The third-party app has a series of different folders where these files sync and that list of folders continues to grow regularly.

I need a solution that allows me to "route" or sync each separate folder within the third-party app-integration's folders to separate and different folders within a different file hierarchy on Dropbox's main file system.

Basically, I want to set up syncing between different folders in the Dropbox Apps folder and different folders in Dropbox's main cloud system.

Solutions I've Considered:

I thought of using Boxifier but their licenses are yearly and too pricey.

FreeFileSync I don't think is robust enough to scale to hundreds and thousands of different directories and thousands and tens of thousands of different files--particularly if every separate file will be a separate task. And I'd preferably want the sync to be real-time (even better if it was entirely cloud-based, but I doubt that exists).

I've also looked at http://www.multicloud.com/, but each real-time sync task automatically pauses after 7 days of inactivity, which will certainly occur. Plus, I find its user interface to be too convoluted to set up new syncs, which I'll be needing to do on a regular basis. I could set up a separate sync task for each set of folders and have that run on a schedule, but again, their user interface does not promote the ease and scale of use that I need.

If there is no available software solution, I thought of possibly some elaborate code involving Command Line or PowerShell, but I'm not very knowledgeable with either option. And because the list would need to be regularly updated, I'd have to constantly be adding to that code.

Perhaps if there was an Excel spreadsheet that would maintain the locations of different folders that need to be synced to other folders and a program/code that regularly or in real-time accessed that spreadsheet to sync files, that could work because I could keep that Excel spreadsheet up to date. But I have no idea how to implement that.

Does anyone have any ideas/thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I remain here to follow the discussion. I didn’t manage to synchronize third-party Apps integrations programs either, so I might be lucky to wait for a specialist :) I don’t want to get into this because of the threat of a [dropbox security breach](https://blog.coupler.io/what-is-dropbox-security/). I read that Dropbox has a great security system, but Internet access in the hands of a fool is a weapon of mass destruction. I wouldn't be surprised if I break some process in trying to set up synchronization, especially if I try to do something that is a priori impossible to do.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).